# Uniqueness of phonon vacuum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, second-quantization, phonons

Consider a quantum harmonic chain, described by the Hamiltonian: $$\hat{H}=\sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{\hat{p_j}}{2M} + \frac{1}{2}K(\hat{u}_j-\hat{u}_{j+1})^2,$$
where $\hat{p}_j$ is the momentum and $\hat{u}_i$ the displacement of $j$-th mass.

We can fourier transform $\hat{u}_i$ and $\hat{p}_j$:
$$\hat{q}_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{j=1}^n \hat{u}_j e^{i\frac{2\pi n}{N}j},$$
$$\hat{\pi}_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{j=1}^n \hat{p}_j e^{i\frac{2\pi n}{N}j}.$$

Define the usuall creation annihilation operators (for $n\ne0$) $\hat{a}_n$ and $\hat{a}_n^\dagger$:

$$\hat{a}_n = \sqrt{\frac{M\omega_n}{2\hbar}}\hat{q}_n +i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2M\hbar\omega_n}}\hat{\pi}_{-n},$$

$$\hat{a}_n^\dagger = \sqrt{\frac{M\omega_n}{2\hbar}}\hat{q}_{-n} -i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2M\hbar\omega_n}}\hat{\pi}_n,$$

and rewrite the Hamiltonian in the form: $$\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}M\hat{\pi}_{0}^2+\sum_{n=-\frac{N-1}{2}, n\ne0}^{\frac{N-1}{2}}\hbar\omega_n(\hat{a}_n^\dagger\hat{a}_n+\frac{1}{2}),$$
where we assumed that the chain contains an odd number of masses.
How can we prove, that for a given value of $\pi_0^2$, there exists exactly one eigenstate of $\hat{\pi}_{0}^2$ annihilated by all $\hat{a}_n$. It is a generalization of the question on how do we prove that the ground state of this system is unique.

Comment: What is $\hat \pi_0$?

Comment: you shouldn't have anything other than $a$'s in your final answer, that's the whole point of changing to the $a$ basis.

Comment: You do need to have the first term. It follows from the fact, that we cannot define creation annihilation operators for $n=0$. The first term is just the kinetic energy of the centre-of-mass motion of the crystal.